# How to show all methods quickly in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

Look at this picture, I should open the `Structure` window every time in Intellij Idea whenever I want to know methods in the class.

Is there a simple way or shortcut to show methods quicky what like `CTRL + O` in Eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> should pop up a member list.  It will respond to text input to search/filter, too.

Comment: For Win10 users, ctrl + fn + F12.

Comment: Doesn't seem to play nice with vim keybindings, let me confirm in a few seconds